# How to disable Telerik radgrid hyperlink column when a specific condition is true

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid, radgridview

I have a Telerik Radgrid. I want to disable hyperlink columns on page load event when a specific condition is true. 
I get role id from the database and on the basis of role id want to disable hyperlink columns on page load event.
my code is here

```
if(RoleId==3)  
{  
btnsave.Enabled= false;

  foreach(griddataitem item in RagGrid1.Items)  
   {  
     HyperLink edit = (hyperlink)item["EditHyperLinkColumn"].Controls[0];  
     edit.Enabled = false;  
   }  
}
```

when the page loads it gets the role id but did not go inside the foreach statement.
Please help.thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

Where did you put your foreach loop in? In Page_Load method? This may not work because RadGrid has its own life cycle and events happen in particular sequence.

What you can do instead is to apply your condition in `ItemDataBound` event.

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e) 
{ 
   if (e.Item is GridDataItem) 
   { 
      var item = (GridDataItem)e.Item; 
      var editlink = item.FindControl("EditHyperLinkColumn") as HyperLink;
      if (editlink != null)
      {
          editlink.Enabled = false;
      }
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the items in the MasterTableView.
Also, verify the UniqueName of the Hyperlink Column. Is it actually "EditHyperLinkColumn"?

```
if(RoleID == 3)
{
    btnsave.Enabled = false;
    foreach(GridDataItem item in RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Items)
    {
        HyperLink edit = (HyperLink)item["EditHyperLinkColumn"].Controls[0];
        edit.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```